# Get mass assignable attributes for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, attributes, mass-assignment

How can i get mass assignable attributes for model?

I found this, but it seems to me kinda dirty.

```
Game.accessible_attributes.to_a.reject{|i| i.empty?}
```

Is there any cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why the is the reject function.

Did you try this :

```
Game.accessible_attributes
```

Comment: You can also do this : Game.accessible_attributes.delete_if {|k, v| v.empty? }